# pygame bullet doesnt appear. bullet is invisble

Tags: python, animation, pygame, bullet

My pygame programm has an issue. My bullet doesnt appear. But I know, that it exist. I tried many thing but nothing helped. I can let it appear but then my player and the bulle start flickering. Pls help. My character also has an moving animation. Pls read at first my code, then answer.  Stackoverflow dont delete my message. Ihr Hurensöhne :)

```
import random

import pygame

# Intialize the pygame
pygame.init()

# create the screen
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 360))

# Background
background = pygame.image.load('SSF2_Final_Valley.png')
walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1a.png'), pygame.image.load('R2a.png'), pygame.image.load('R3a.png'), pygame.image.load('R4a.png'), pygame.image.load('R5a.png'), pygame.image.load('R6a.png'), pygame.image.load('R7a.png'), pygame.image.load('R8a.png'), pygame.image.load('R9a.png')]
walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1a.png'), pygame.image.load('L2a.png'), pygame.image.load('L3a.png'), pygame.image.load('L4a.png'), pygame.image.load('L5a.png'), pygame.image.load('L6a.png'), pygame.image.load('L7a.png'), pygame.image.load('L8a.png'), pygame.image.load('L9a.png')]
char = pygame.image.load('stand.png')


vel = 5
width = 64
screen_width = 640
left = False
right = False
clockobject = pygame.time.Clock()


#player
playerImg = pygame.image.load('stand.png')
playerX = 15
playerY = 290
playerX_change = 0

# Bullet

# Ready - You can't see the bullet on the screen
# Fire - The bullet is currently moving

bulletImg = pygame.image.load('kunai.png')
bulletX = 15
bulletY = 290 - 32
bulletX_change = 3
bulletY_change = 0
bullet_state = "ready"

def redrawGameWindow():
    global player
    def player(x, y):
        global walkCount
        screen.blit(background, (0,0))
        #chracter wird gezecihnet
        if walkCount + 1 >= 20:
            walkCount = 0
        if left:
            screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
            walkCount += 1
            
        elif right:
            screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x, y))
            walkCount += 1
            
            
    global fire_bullet   
    def fire_bullet(x, y):
        global bullet_state
        bullet_state = "fire"
        screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 32, y + 32))
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))
    


"""def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 32, y + 32))
    pygame.display.update()"""
    
running = True
while running:
    # RGB = Red, Green, Blue
    #screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    # Background Image
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            exit()
            

        # if keystroke is pressed check whether its right or left
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                if bullet_state is "ready":
                    
                    # Get the current x cordinate of the spaceship
                    bulletX = playerX
                    fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)

                
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and playerX > vel:
        playerX -= vel
        left = True
        right = False
        
    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and playerX < screen_width- width :
        playerX += vel
        right = True
        left = False
        
    else:
        right = False
        left = False
        walkCount = 0
        
                
    # 5 = 5 + -0.1 -> 5 = 5 - 0.1
    # 5 = 5 + 0.1

    playerX += playerX_change
    """if playerX <= 0:
        playerX = 0
    elif playerX >= 640 - 64:
        playerX = 608 - 64"""

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    redrawGameWindow()
    if bulletX <= 0:
        bulletX = 15
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
        bulletX += bulletX_change
        
    if (bulletX > screen_width-width):
        bullet_state = "ready"
        
        
    if keys[pygame.K_f]:
        playerX = bulletX
    player(playerX, playerY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the functions `player` and `fire_bullet` from the function `redrawGameWindow`. `player` and `fire_bullet` have to be functions in global namespace. However `redrawGameWindow` has to invoke the functions `player` and `fire_bullet`. Draw the background and update the display in `redrawGameWindow`:

```py
def player(x, y):
    global walkCount
    if walkCount + 1 >= 20:
        walkCount = 0
    if left:
        screen.blit(walkLeft[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    elif right:
        screen.blit(walkRight[walkCount//3], (x, y))
        walkCount += 1
    else:
        screen.blit(char, (x, y))          
             
def fire_bullet(x, y):
    global bullet_state
    bullet_state = "fire"
    screen.blit(bulletImg, (x + 32, y + 32))

def redrawGameWindow():
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    player(playerX, playerY)
    if bullet_state is "fire":
        fire_bullet(bulletX, bulletY)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Call `redrawGameWindow` at the end of the application loop:

```py
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(60)

    # [...]

    if bulletX <= 0:
        bulletX = 15
        bullet_state = "ready"

    if bullet_state is "fire":
        bulletX += bulletX_change
        
    if (bulletX > screen_width-width):
        bullet_state = "ready"
        
    if keys[pygame.K_f]:
        playerX = bulletX
        
    redrawGameWindow()
```